# How to change max http header size in react

Tags: php, node.js, reactjs, http-headers

I'm new to react and trying to send a fetch or ajax request to a PHP script, initially I was receiving a 404 response but I read I had to place this:

`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000');`

at the top of the php script but after that the responses changed to:

`431: (Request Header Fields Too Large)`.

I read the problem is from the max http header size being small so I want to know if it is possible to increase the it and if yes how do I do that.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not your answer but You can use axios better than using fetch and much easier

Comment: Still getting the same responses

Comment: Can you post her sample of your request

Answer (score 0):

clear you your cookies in browser & try again.
If it's not working, add `"proxy" : "http://localhost:3000"` in your `package.json`

Thanks

Comment: I have tried that too